# Change Boolean values to button in angular 2 client side

Tags: typescript, angular

### Details

I am trying to get data from api and show into the table. One of the columns contains status attribute which return true or false value but I want to show Active or Block buttons instead of this status, ie. if status is true then show delete button and if status==false show active button. How can I able to achieve this in angular 2.

### Image

[image: Image describing my problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do something like this:

considering `status:boolean=true;`

in your template you can use *ngIf as:

```
<div>
    <button *ngIf="status==true">Delete</button>
    <button *ngIf="status==false">Active</button>
</div>
```

or you could also use `ngSwitch` too.

Hope this helps.